# What does * mean in linux for gateway ip?

Tags: ethernet, linux

To be more precise, after running netstat -r , I got the following lines:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         199.170.12.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
199.170.12.0    *               255.255.254.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

The reason why I run it was that my Ethernet connection wasn't working in linux, even though it was working on windows (installed in the same machine). 
I was using dynamic ip, the previous time the connection was working fine and I hadn't done any changes. I first checked ifconfig and it was all normal. I checked the resolv.conf and it was pointing to the nameserver 127.0.1.1 (that was ok as well - as far as I know).

The only thing that I found suspicious was the gateway ip (it may be normal, but to be honest I hadn't tried this command before and I don't know what * means).

Then the connection was fixed (all by itself, I didn't do anything). But I wanted to ask anyway.

Comment: `netstat -rn` should answer your question

Answer (score 1):

It means that it doesn't need a gateway to reach that subnet.  That's a local subnet, so it doesn't need a next-hop IP.  With `netstat -r`, there appears to be better context friendliness.  `0.0.0.0` in the destination section translates to `default`, whereas in the gateway section it translates to `*`.

```
rj@Latitude-E6410:~$ netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

---

```
rj@Latitude-E6410:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

Answer (score 0):

In Netstat, the `-r` switch displays the kernel routing table.

By default, netstat tries to resolve the IP to its name by doing a reverse DNS lookup. For this to work, (presuming BIND as the DNS server)there should be a reverse zone data file with PTR resource records which will map IP address-to-name. Usually this is not configured in Home networks (and many production networks for that matter).

When netstat doesn't get any response from the DNS server beyond the default timeout value (you can set one by specifying the `timeout:n` directive in the `/etc/resolv.conf` where n measured in seconds), `*` appears in places where the networking keyword *ANY* is appropriate, which is equivalent to `0.0.0.0`. The interpretation of `*` is context specific. In your case, like Ryan Foley said to reach the network `192.168.1.0/24` no gateway is required as that's your local network.

You can learn how to interpret the netstat output and its usage by reading [this blog](https://deepakdevanand.wordpress.com/2014/11/20/netstat/). The `-n` switch disables the reverse DNS lookup which makes the netstat speedy.

*Following are the possibilities that might have occurred in your case:*

1. The client needs to get the IP from the DHCP server. When the machine boots up, the DHCP protocol is initiated. This conversation includes DHCP DORA(Discover, Offer, Request,Ack) packets. Out of these, DHCP Discover is a broadcast from the machine. Depending upon the no. of nodes in the network(same collision domain), it takes a while for the DHCP server to get this Discover packet and reply with the DHCP Offer which contains the IP.
2. Next is the `arp resolution`. Having IP address doesn't make the machine to be able to communicate unless the ARP table is built. This has the IP-to-MAC address mapping. The MAC address is the requisite to form the packet and send it on the physical wire(`ether`). Again learning MAC address of the machines in the local network involves ARP broadcast(request) and unicasts(reply). This adds to the time before which the machine is ready to communicate.
3. The causes for delay include too many packet collisions, TCP parameter negotiation like window size, timer initializations, queue length etc., packet buffer full at the destination, switching delay among others.